# Graphics on Visio presentations

Tags: visio, visio2013

I have created a network diagram on Visio, but now my customer is asking that if during the presentation he clicks on any of the network devices a photo of that device should pop-up with a brief description.

Is that possible in Visio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you could accomplish this:
1. You can have as many hyperlinks as you like on each shape in Visio.
2. You can link to another page in the same Visio document.
3. You can write code (VBA or other) to open a custom form.

If you are presenting in a web page, then perhaps the first is the best solution.